# Can I add a sound to play when I lock my workstation?

Tags: gnome, audio, screen-lock

I am currently on CentOS7 Gnome and want to play a sound when I lock my workstation, I've looked through few sounds schemes and none of them seem to be providing this sound, is there a list of available gnome mappings?
How would I go about adding additional one if the one for "desktop-lock" doesn't exist. 
Is perhaps Gnome a bit stale and should I perhaps move onto different Desktop Environment if I want to to use RHEL compatible system for personal use i.e give it a bit of sass and customise.